# Configured Log level is not working as expected

Tags: ballerina

### Problem:

I have configured `log.level` in `Config.toml` as described in the release notes [here](https://ballerina.io/downloads/swan-lake-release-notes/swan-lake-alpha3/#introduced-additional-log-levels-and-log-functions). However, my `log:printDebug(....)` statements in the code aren't printing the debug logs. I do still get INFO and above logs.

### Environment:

```
Ballerina 2201.3.1 (Swan Lake Update 3)
Language specification 2022R4
Update Tool 1.3.11
```

Answer (score 3):

The following entry needs to be used to enable debug logs (which is a bit different compared to the entry in the release note you've pointed to - requires `ballerina.log` instead of just `log`).

```ini
[ballerina.log]
level = "DEBUG"
```

The [log example](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/logging-configuration) also demonstrates additional configuration (including per-module configuration).

Also, the `Config.toml` file has to be [in the current working directory if the location is not explicitly specified](https://ballerina.io/learn/configure-ballerina-programs/provide-values-to-configurable-variables).

Comment: would someone be taking a note/raising an issue to update the doco?

Comment: This did not work :(

Comment: Are there any other configurations (e.g., `configurable` variables) in the code? Just to make sure the `Config.toml` file is being picked as expected. Alternatively, you can try specifying the path using the `BAL_CONFIG_FILES` environment variable. 

Regarding the release note, given that this was the Swan Lake Alpha3 release note, we will check what the key was at the time and update the release note if changes are required.

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to Ballerina alpha version "documentation" that is outdated, not guaranteed to be valid but for that specific alpha version and should not be referred anymore. It has mostly only historical value.

The correct documentation for can be found from:

- https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/logging-configuration/
- https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/log/2.5.0